# Downloadable pdf in JasperReports

Tags: java, web-applications, jasper-reports

I am working with JasperReprots. This is part of my code:

```
ServletContext context = this.getServletConfig().getServletContext();
                File reportF = new File(context.getRealPath(rF));
                byte[] bytes = null;
                ServletOutputStream servletOutputStream = resp.getOutputStream();
                InputStream reportStream = new FileInputStream(reportF.getPath());
                reportF.delete();
                bytes = JasperRunManager.runReportToPdf(reportStream,  new HashMap(),new JREmptyDataSource());
                resp.setContentType("application/pdf");
                resp.setContentLength(bytes.length);
                servletOutputStream.write(bytes, 0, bytes.length);
                servletOutputStream.flush();
                servletOutputStream.close();
```

After this I can see pdf in my browser, but when I try to save it, the file has no extension pdf. How to add this extension without saving report on my server?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should probably do the trick:

```
resp.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=report.pdf");
```

Comment: Ok. I've mede few changes in my code, and I have used your advice, and it works. I think that there is a mistake in your line of code. It should be: resp.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"report.pdf\"");

Comment: Glad to hear it worked. It's weird though, I've used the code in my answer as it is, and it worked just fine.